# DataTime in Perseo CEP

Tags: fiware, complex-event-processing, fiware-perseo

I am using CEP to modify type date fields with update mode.

Entities:

```
{
  "id":"controller",
  "type":"control",
  "lasmodify":{
    "type":"DataTime",
    "value":""
    }
 }

{
   "id":"Device01",
   "type":"device",
   "id_controller":{
      "type":"Text",
      "value":"controller01"
    }
   "datemodify":{
   "type":"DataTime",
   "value":"2018-12-04T20:05:00.00Z"
   }
 }
```

I want that the Device01 subscription is shooted, the controller01 attribute lasmodify will be modified with datemodify of device01 entity.

Thank you very much in advance
Best regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i have understood correctly, you want to update the controler when CEP recibes a device change notification.
The solution should be something similar to this rule:

```
{
   "name":"update_rule",
   "text":"select ev.controler? as controlerID, ev.datemodify? as newDate, \"update_rule\" as ruleName from pattern [every ev=iotEvent(type=\"device\")]",
   "action":{
      "type":"update",
      "parameters":{
          "id":"${controlerID}",
          "type":"control",
          "attributes": [
                {
                "name":"lasmodify",
                "type":"DataTime"
                "value":"${newDate}"
                }
          ]
      }
   }
}
```

I don't know what version of Perseo you use, but using the latest fiware image for [perseo-fe](https://hub.docker.com/r/fiware/perseo) and [perseo-core](https://hub.docker.com/r/fiware/perseo-core), you could omit the ruleName and use NGSIv2

```
{
   "name":"update_rule",
   "text":"select ev.controler? as controlerID, ev.datemodify? as newDate from pattern [every ev=iotEvent(type=\"device\")]",
   "action":{
      "type":"update",
      "parameters":{
          "id":"${controlerID}",
          "type":"control",
          "version": "2",
          "attributes": [
                {
                "name":"lasmodify",
                "type":"DataTime"
                "value":"${newDate}"
                }
          ]
      }
   }
}
```